# Por que quando faço "commit", meu projeto fica cheio de erros?

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Recentemente comecei a trabalhar com GitHub para commitar meus projetos mas de vez em quando percebo algo muito chato: meu projeto fica CHEIO de erros, o que mais vejo é:

<<<<<<<<<"HEAD
=========="
<<<575439787438

Por que isso aconteceu? tem como evitar?

Comment: É um problema de merge.

Comment: isso são conflitos que voce precisa resolver antes de subir, pode reparar que logo abaixo dessa marcação vai ter um trecho de código antigo que voce modificou ou identico, caod a alteração não seja nesse trecho especifico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não ocorre especificamente no commit, e sim na hora de você efetuar um push ou pull.

O motivo é que você tem uma versão diferente do repositório, e alguem efetuou mudanças no código na mesma parte que você.

Quando você tenta sincronizar (push/pull) o repositório remoto, para efetuar as mudanças o git realiza o que chamamos de merge (mescla) do código. Geralmente isso ocorre sem problemas, quando não há conflitos.

Um conflito ocorre quando há dois commits que geralmente alteraram a mesma parte de um código, e com isso, o git não consegue resolver automáticamente, desta forma, ele coloca alguns marcadores de conflitos (conflict markers) para sinalizar onde ocorreu o conflito.

Exemplo:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
foo
=======
bar
>>>>>>> cb1abc6bd98cfc84317f8aa95a7662815417802d
```

[Fonte](https://wincent.com/wiki/Understanding_Git_conflict_markers)

A parte onde diz `<<<<<<< HEAD` significa que esta é a parte do seu código local, que está na sua branch onde foi feito o merge.

A parte onde diz `====` e `>>>>>>> cb1abc6bd...` significa o início e fim do commit de onde você efetuou o pull, e é nesta parte onde ocorreu o conflito.

**O que você deve fazer?**

Analisar corretamente a parte que deu conflito, pois como duas pessoas efetuaram alterações na mesma parte do código, o mais recomendado é que seja alinhado com a pessoa responsável pelo commit o que foi feito de fato, e o que pode ser feito para integrar a sua parte do código com a da pessoa responsável, para que ambos não percam o trabalho feito.
Ao final, retire os `conflict marks` e efetue outro commit, identificado como `merge`.

Para mais sobre o assunto, recomendo a seguinte leitura na documentação oficial do git (em inglês):

[Merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)